# Objective c: Comparing String on basis of common pattern

Tags: objective-c

I have two strings.

```
NSString *a=@"1_2";
NSString *b=@"1_3";
```

I want to compare these two string .I want that these two string should be equal. By equal I mean first two characters are the same.

**Is there any method which can compare these two string?**

Comment: What are your criteria for determining that they are equal?

Comment: You need define exactly *why* these strings should be considered equal. Do you want to only compare the first characters? The first two? Something entirely different?

Comment: @DarkDust i want to compare the first two characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ([[a substringToIndex:2] isEqualToString:[b substringToIndex:2]]) {
    NSLog(@"equal");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method to compare only the first two characters:

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compareFirstTwoCharactersOf:(NSString *)str1 with:(NSString *)str2
{
    if ([str1 length] < 2) {
        // Receiver too short, fall back.
        return [str1 compare:str2];
    } else {
        return [str1 compare:str2 options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, 2)]; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ([a isEqualToString:b]) {
    NSLog(@"equal");
}
```

Comment: I think that is not what he wants. He wants that @"1_2" equals @"1_3".

Comment: @Thedude Yes,I want the two string to be equal on basis of their common pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You should use regular expressions.  You should create a regular expression that corresponds to "digit underscore digit", and then if a and b fit the expression then they both are "equal" the way you want them to be, not literally equal of course.

Check this out:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html

As an example, a regular expression that matches "digit underscore digit" should be: \d_\d

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\d_\d" options:0 error:NULL];
NSString *a = @"1_2";
NSString *b = @"1_3";
NSTextCheckingResult *matchA = [regex firstMatchInString:a options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [a length])];
NSTextCheckingResult *matchB = [regex firstMatchInString:b options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [b length])];
if(matchA && matchB){
    //Strings match the same pattern
}
```